# How do I define relationships between User, Post and Like models

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js, phpmyadmin

I'm building a blogging app with laravel with the functionality to like a post (only once by a user) with a thumbs-up icon. I have set up a model each for User, Post and Like with their respective tables. The likes table consist of user_id,post_id and the timestamps columns. I have also defined relationships between User and Post models like so:
Inside User model:

```
Public function post(){
    return $this->hasMany (App\Post)
} 
Public function like(){
    return $this->hasMany (App\Like)
}
```

and inside Post model;

```
Public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo (App\User)
}
```

My challenge however is in writing a relationship between Post and Like models. What relationships will exist between both models?

Comment: Is your likes table a pivot table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need Like model, because you can create direct relation between User and Post, but with different table name, e.g. "likes".

User model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, "likes");
}
```

Post model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "likes");
}
```

More about Many to Many relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many